# dispform.aspx open link in new tab

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using Sharepoint 2010 and I have a requirement where I have to remove all the hyperlinks from dispform.aspx but not to the file name so that users can open the file from there. I achieved this using the javscript below on dispform.aspx. But now the users want to open the link in new window/tab when they click the file name. I tried doing that using the "else if" condition in below code. But it is not working. Can someone help me with this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function DisableLinks()
    {
     var x = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
     for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
     {
       if (x(i).href.indexOf("DispForm.aspx")>-1)
       {

        x(i).removeAttribute("onclick");
        x(i).removeAttribute("href");
       }
       else if(x(i).href.indexOf(".pdf")>-1)
       {
          x(i).setAttribute('target', '_blank');

       }
    }
 }

 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("DisableLinks"); 
</script>
```

Also, it is modal dialog window. Does this makes any difference? If i use developer tools I see that the 'A' tag has the attribute target=_blank. But for some reason the link is still opening in same window

Comment: Is your link for the PDF similar to this one? <a rel="sp_DialogLinkNavigate" href="xxxx/xxxx/xxx.docx" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, '1', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3', '')" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3', '1', ''); return false;">xxxxx</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for any JavaScript attached to the link and see about removing that.

```
<a rel="sp_DialogLinkNavigate" href="xxxx/xxxx/xxx.docx" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, '1', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3', '')" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3', '1', ''); return false;">xxxxx</a>
```

This is a link I've taken from a dialog in my SharePoint 2010. I don't know exactly what yours looks like but I would start by removing the **onmousedown** and **onclick**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. I chanhged the brackets but still no luck. And please note that the code is working fine to remove the hyperlinks even without changing the brackets. The only thing that is not working is opening the link in new window.

Comment: Do you have any example html of what is actually in your SharePoint page? (the links in particular)

Comment: Thanks chris. I removed the onmousedown and onclick and added the attribute target and it worked like a charm. thank you so much for the help.